# How can I display a nested JSON string using a JQuery Mobile nested list?

Tags: json, mobile, jquery-mobile, nested-lists

I have found a lot plugins that can display nested JSON on a desktop ,like jTree. They works  well in a full desktop environment, but when run on mobile phones, there are some problems. Generally, the line is sometimes too long, or in short, it's ugly.

So, I want to display it in a jQuery Mobile nested  list (like our mobilephones filemanager.)

Is there some jQuery Mobile plugin(s) or some other solutions I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard release of JQuery Mobile 1.2 has Nested Lists (similar to browsing a file manager on a smartphone i.e. click on directory and it brings up more directories and files)

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-nested.html

**via Serverside Script**

You could create a single script page that dynamically loads the JSON node as a parameter within `$.mobile.changePage()`.  You should be able to create the current view of the tree from this.

**via Javascript DOM**

If you're doing this by updating the DOM with javascript, I believe after you have updated the DOM with the current view of your JSON tree, you have to run `$('#mylist').listview('refresh')` to update the styling.